# ADAM (MSExchange) VSS Writer - Non-retryable error (when backing up with DPM, or makinng Hyperv checkpoint)

Tags: windows, backup, hyper-v, vss, scdpm

I have Exchange EDGE ROLE installed as VM on Hyper-v (Win 2016 std).

**When DPM 2016 tries to backup that VM I have an error that it is failing**, I tracked the problem to inability to make VSS snapshot because **ADAM (MSExchange) Writer** is failing with state 11. (DPM trigers Hyperv checkpoint on vm host, which trigers VSS shapshot on guest OS, which uses VSS writers)

Does anybody had similar problem, there is not much info if you Google it, only about registry key missing, thath I have checkeh and it is ok on my instalation.

[writer error snf registry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8K9h.png)

[event viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CL9U.png)

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue, except using Veeam.  Seems to be to do with the new 'checkpoint' backup process introduced in Server 2016.  Your guest can't successfully complete an application consistent snapshot.

On the veeam forum they have running version 6.3.9600.17903 of vmbus.sys seems to solve this issue for exchange.  The relevant update is here.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3071740/hyper-v-integration-components-update-for-windows-virtual-machines-that-are-running-on-a-windows-10-based-host

Later versions of the hyper-v integration tools update and break this.

Many vendors are saying this is a Microsoft known issue.  However I cannot find anything where microsoft have acknowledged this.

Similar problems exist for backing up AD servers on 2016 hosts as well.

Comment: Even now I still keep this VM with "production checkpoints" disabled, DPM backups this VM with no errors if "production checkpoints" are disabled.